# Javascript error Facebook "Unexpected token /" in russian version of all.js

Tags: facebook

I'm using russian version of facebook script:

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js'></script>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
```

For some reason, I started to observe errors on our web site, it is happening in facebook script:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
in all.js:7

obviously when I click share, `FB is not defined`

Important: I also tryed with en_US version of script, and it is working fine

screen shot included[image: Facebook Error using Russian script]

Comment: Could you try loading the SDK asynchronously?

Comment: you mean load script trough (document).ready( ... ?

Comment: No, I mean like [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5334977/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-facebook-javascript-sdk-loaded-successfully/5336483#5336483).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it was fixed by FB